# How to access a data formatted by a function in OOP python

Tags: python, oop

I can't access some data formatted by a function using OOP in python:

```
class Menu:
    """Models the Menu with drinks."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.menu = [
            MenuItem(name="latte", water=200, milk=150, coffee=24, cost=2.5),
            MenuItem(name="espresso", water=50, milk=0, coffee=18, cost=1.5),
            MenuItem(name="cappuccino", water=250, milk=50, coffee=24, cost=3),
        ]
```

```
1.  from menu import Menu
2.  from coffee_maker import CoffeeMaker
3.  from money_machine import MoneyMachine
4.  
5.  print("HOT COFFEE!")
6.  print("Here is the coffee menu!")
7.  menu1 = Menu()
8.  mycoffee = CoffeeMaker()
9.  print("Here are the resources available to make coffee!")
10. mycoffee.report()
11. order = input("Choose the type of coffee you want: ")
12. menu1.find_drink(order)
13. mymoney = MoneyMachine()
14. mymoney.process_coins()
15. mymoney.make_payment(**menu[order][cost]**)
16. if mymoney.make_payment() == True:
17.   if mycoffee.is_resource_sufficient(order) == True:
18.     mycoffee.make_coffee()
```

The bold text in line 15 is causing me headaches. I don't know how to access the **cost** in the Menu class.

I tried :
`mymoney.make_payment(menu[order][cost])`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a new function on the class which helps to get the cost information. Assuming MenuItem class has a private attribute named "cost" and Menu class can access its attributes

```
Class Menu:
.
.
.
def get_cost(self, drink):
    return drink.cost
```

In your other script:

```
.
.
drink = menu1.find_drink(order) #its better to have a structure like this instead of calling the function directly.
order = menu1.get_cost(drink)
```